# BIO don't flush data in OpenSSL

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I am using BIO to compute the digest of some file with OpenSSL. My code is as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

int main(){

    BIO* bio_infile;
    bio_infile = BIO_new_file("test.txt", "rb");
    
    BIO* bio_md = BIO_new(BIO_f_md());
    BIO_set_md(bio_md, EVP_sha1());

    BIO* bio_outfile;
    bio_outfile = BIO_new_file("dgst.txt","w");
    
    BIO_push(bio_md, bio_outfile);
    BIO_push(bio_infile, bio_md);
    
    BIO_flush(bio_infile);
    BIO_flush(bio_md);
    
    BIO_free(bio_infile); 
    BIO_free(bio_md);
    BIO_free(bio_outfile);
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, When my program run out, I find nothings in file `dgst.txt`.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BIO` chaining mechanism is meant for prepending filter `BIO`s to a source/sink `BIO`. It is not designed for connecting a source `BIO` with a sink `BIO`.

So what you can do:

- Create a `BIO` chain of filters with a final `BIO` sink. When writing data to the head of the chain, the input will traverse each filter until it reaches the sink.
- Create a `BIO` chain of filters with a final `BIO` source. When reading data from the head of the chain, the read request will be passed along the chain up to the source. The data read from the source will then traverse the chain in the reverse direction through each filter.

But what you can not do:

- Creating a `BIO` chain that starts with a source and ends with a sink with filters in between. There is no mechanism for "pumping" data from the source to the sink automatically.

One additional note: The `BIO_f_md` is a filter `BIO` that calculates the digest of the data passing through it, but it does not modify the data. So the output of the `BIO` is the original data, not the digest of the data. The digest can be retrieved after all data has been processed with `BIO_get_md` ([reference](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/BIO_get_md.html)). So in your example, even if there was support for chaining a source to  a sink, the final `dgst.txt` would only contain the original data from `test.txt`.

To fix your example, there are two approaches:

### Approach 1

Create a chain with the digest `BIO` followed by the source `BIO` for the input file. We can then read from the digest `BIO`, which internally pulls the data from the source `BIO`. We read the data and immediately discard it until the complete file has been processed. We can then retrieve the digest from the digest `BIO`.

```
    // Create chain: Digest -> Source File
    BIO* bio_infile;
    bio_infile = BIO_new_file("test.txt", "rb");

    BIO* bio_md = BIO_new(BIO_f_md());
    BIO_set_md(bio_md, EVP_sha1());

    BIO* head = BIO_push(bio_md, bio_infile);

    // Read from head of chain
    std::array<char,1024> buf{};
    int read;

    while ((read = BIO_read(head, buf.data(), buf.size())) > 0) {
      // Ignore buffer, we only want the data to pass throug the digest BIO
    }

    // Read result from digest BIO
    EVP_MD *md;
    BIO_get_md(bio_md, &md);

    std::array<char, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE> md_buf{};
    int mdlen = BIO_gets(bio_md, md_buf.data(), md_buf.size());

    // Print digest to stdout
    for (int i = 0; i < mdlen; i++) {
      printf("%02x", static_cast<uint8_t>(md_buf[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Cleanup
    BIO_free_all(head);
```

### Approach 2

Create a chain with the digest `BIO` followed by a special sink `BIO` for discarding data (`BIO_s_null`). We then read the data from source `BIO` for the input file (without any chaining) and write the data to the digest `BIO`. The written data passes through the digest `BIO` to the sink `BIO`, which will discard the data. When all data has been processed, we can retrieve the digest from the digest `BIO`.

```
    // Create chain: Digest -> Null Sink
    BIO* bio_infile;
    bio_infile = BIO_new_file("test.txt", "rb");

    BIO* bio_md = BIO_new(BIO_f_md());
    BIO_set_md(bio_md, EVP_sha1());

    BIO* bio_null = BIO_new(BIO_s_null());

    BIO* head = BIO_push(bio_md, bio_null);

    // Read from file and write to chain
    std::array<char,1024> buf{};
    int read;

    while ((read = BIO_read(bio_infile, buf.data(), buf.size())) > 0) {
      BIO_write(head, buf.data(), read);
    }

    // Read result from digest BIO
    EVP_MD *md;
    BIO_get_md(bio_md, &md);

    std::array<char, EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE> md_buf{};
    int mdlen = BIO_gets(bio_md, md_buf.data(), md_buf.size());

    // Print digest to stdout
    for (int i = 0; i < mdlen; i++) {
      printf("%02x", static_cast<uint8_t>(md_buf[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Cleanup
    BIO_free(bio_infile);
    BIO_free_all(head);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very good. After read it, I understand the mechanism of BIO in OpenSSL.